# How to save and access a larger array to hdf5 file: Memory error?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, hdf5, h5py

I have to save three arrays: 40000x2x128x128x128, 40000x128x128x128 and 40000x128x128x128 to a single hdf5 file. I used the below code to randomly assign the value to each array and write it to the hdf5 file. However, I have two issues here:

> 1. The array is too big, then it will have a memory error. I cannot run all iterations due to memory error. How could we fix it?
> 2. The output hdf5 is too big, about 40GB. How can we load it to RAM? Because each time I just randomly pick up some position in the array to process

This is my code

```
var_1_h5 = np.zeros((4000 *10, 2, 128,128,128),dtype=np.float32)
var_2_h5 = np.zeros((4000 *10, 128,128,128),dtype=np.float32)
var_3_h5 = np.zeros((4000 *10, 128,128,128),dtype=np.uint8)
for i in range (1, 10):
    for j in range (4000):
        var_1 = np.random.randn(2, 128,128,128) 
        var_2 = np.random.randn(128,128,128)
        var_3 = np.random.randint(128,128,128)
        var_1_h5[j]=var_1
        var_2_h5[j]=var_2
        var_3_h5[j]=var_3
with h5py.File('var.h5', 'w') as f:
    f['var_1'] = var_1_h5
    f['var_2'] = var_2_h5
    f['var_3'] = var_3_h5
```

Comment: do you solved the issue? I also have to same problem 
to writing a large file to the h5py file this takes too much memory